# Contact Id on opportunities

Tags: api, contact

So I am trying to create Opportunities for Contacts, but I can't seem to get the contact ID from the opp like I could Account Id's. Does anyone know if this is possible? I checked out the sobject description and I couldn't really see anything in there either that would definitively answer my question. Anyone know if this is possible via the API?

Comment: have you find solution for this, any code? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacts are associated with accounts just like opportunities - they're both children in lookup relationships:

[image]

So you can either traverse up to the account and then hunt for associated contact Ids, if you're starting at opportunity, or you can create a new custom lookup field on contact that points to opportunity and create opportunities from there. Your contact detail page could have  an opportunity related list if you went with a custom lookup.

Without adding the lookup on contact, it's not really possible to get *the* contact that you're creating an opportunity for since account to contact is a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Completely understandable. The one question I do have is how the GUI associates contacts and opportunities. I'm not using person accounts, so an account can have many contacts. In the GUI, I can attach an opportunity directly to a contact OR the Account, but it doesn't see to work that way with the API. Is this the case?

Comment: I've actually just figured it out. It technically doesn't attach it to a contact. We have a lookup field on the opp for the contact, which is where I was thinking it was attaching it. Thanks for your help on this one.

Comment: No problem. You might look at OpportunityContactRole for more info on how the standard UI is linking things under the hood. It's a junction object that performs that magic.