# How to associate a contact with an opportunity using Restforce or REST API?

Tags: rest-api, api, opportunity, contact

I tried submitting a `ContactId` with the Opportunity, but received

```
ERROR: INVALID_FIELD: No such column 'ContactId' on sobject of type Opportunity
```

Is there any documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the schema, there is no OOTB field ContactId on Opportunity

Instead, you use the junction object: [OpportunityContactRole](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_opportunitycontactrole.htm?search_text=opportunitycontactrole) which has two lookup keys

- ContactId
- OpportunityId

Of course, you can always add a custom field on Opportunity such as `ContactId__c` and you should check with your org's schema to see if this was already done

In general, you want to use the OpportunityContactRole as more than one contact can be associated with an Opportunity and many managed packages rely on this relationship to do useful things (e.g. Hubspot tracks Deals this way)

Comment: OK, thank you. I found that info here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16084/contact-id-on-opportunities

Comment: Thanks for your help. Implementing `OpportunityContactRole` via REST API was straightforward. Do I need to use `IsPrimary ` or `Role` fields?

Comment: @BSeven - nope - per the Object doc, `IsPrimary` is defaulted on Create and `Role` is optional. If you do use roles, they have to be ones defined already in metadata: `Setup | Customize | Opportunities | Contact Roles on Opportunities`

Comment: FWIW, IsPrimary defaults to false using Restforce for me. I guess there could be some config that is causing it...

Comment: @BSeven - so, if you want it to be TRUE, you'll need to set that in your REST POST body